# any solution to Matlab VideoReader on compressed avi file on Mac?

Tags: matlab, ffmpeg, h.264, avi, video-compression

I am working on some video gamma correction. And I used some sample avi uncompressed clips from online, everything works just fine. 
But once I try to use our own .avi video 1280x800 20 second about 400mb, Matlab can not read file through 'VideoReader'.

I'm really sure the problem is that my video is compressed avi. And I have tried the following to solve it:

1. some say in mac os, download gstreamer 0.10 may help. I did, but problem remained.
2. i tried to use ffmpeg to convert the compressed avi to uncompressed avi (i dont think i am supposed to do this tho). but the new uncompressed video became a mess.

So, I was thinking, when working on compressed avi file in MATLAB in mac, is there a godd routine that people follow?

Thanks a lot.